# Deploy a Java Google Function on Google Cloud using Serverless Framework

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, serverless-framework

I’m trying to deploy a simple google Function written in Java, but something is going wrong.
this is my serverless.yaml

```
service: report-connector

provider:
    name: google
    runtime: java11
    region: ${opt:region}
    project: report-connector
    credentials: ~/.gcloud/keyfile.json

    deploymentBucket:
        name: report
    deploymentPrefix: deploy

package:
    artifact: target/${self:service}.jar

functions:
    getReport:
        handler: GetReport
        name: GetReport
        description: Get Report
        events:
            - http:
            path: /getReport
```

When I run the command:

```
serverless deploy --region europe-west3
```

I get this stack:

```
$ serverless deploy --region europe-west3 -v
Serverless: Packaging service…
```

and nothing else.

Could you help me to figure out the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem

Comment: It is awesome that you solved the problem, could you please write an Answer in case another person stumbles upon the same issue?

Comment: Hi @JaneJetson, I solved using another way to deploy it. Serverless Framework, in this case, don't work very well yet. I build the java project with maven, using compile plugin to inlcude all dependencies; then I zip the jar and then create the Google Function direct from the Google Console. I hope this help all of you. Write me for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by following steps:

1. Build the java project with maven
2. Use a compile plugin to include all dependencies
3. Zip the jar and then create the Google Function direct from the Google Console.